# How to tell if a list has already been loaded?

Tags: java, linked-list, treeset

I have a Java program that allows teachers to load and list students with a GPA higher than what has been entered by the user. The program features 3 classes: one which provides the get and set methods for each student (`Student`), one that provides four different options from which the teachers can choose (`Communicator`), and a class which calls the `Communicator` class to start up (`HW4`). The four options in the `Communicator` class include 1) loading lists of students using text files, 2) displaying students with a GPA higher than the GPA entered by the user, 3) printing a loaded log of files that have been loaded into the program, and 4) exit the program.

I have all the basic parts of each program working. However, I'm having difficulty with the program recognizing if a file has already been loaded, to which it should reply "File already loaded!" Each file loaded into the program is added to a TreeSet called "logHistory," and I tried using an if statement that basically will print out that the file has already been loaded if the log history contains the input. However, it simply prints out "[text file] loaded successfully! File already loaded!" even if I've already entered it once. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Here is my code for each class:

HW4.java:

```java
public class HW4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Start communicator
        Communicator.start();

    }

}
```

Student.java:

```java
public class Student {

        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private float gpa;
        
        public Student(String firstName, String lastName, float gpa){
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.gpa = gpa;         
        }
        
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }
        
        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
        
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
        
        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
        
        public float getGPA() {
            return gpa;
        }
        
        public void setGPA(float gpa) {
            this.gpa = gpa;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student{" + "First Name = " + firstName + ", Last Name = " + lastName + ", GPA = " + gpa + '}';
        }
}
```

Communicator.java:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Communicator {

    static Set<String> logHistory;
    
    static LinkedList<Student> studentList;
    
    public static void start() throws Exception{
        logHistory = new TreeSet<String>();
        studentList = new LinkedList<Student>();
        System.out.println("Hello professor. How can I help you?");
        displayMainMenu();
    }
    
    public static void displayMainMenu() throws Exception {
        
        String input;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.printf("1: Load student list.\n");
            System.out.printf("2: Display students by gpa.\n");
            System.out.printf("3: Print load log.\n");
            System.out.printf("4: Exit.\n");
            System.out.printf(">> ");
            input = in.next();
            if(invalidInput(input)) {
                continue;
            }
        
        switch(input) {
        case "1":
            OptionOne();
            break;
        case "2":
            OptionTwo();
            break;
        case "3":
            printLog();
            break;
        case "4":
            System.out.println("Good bye! :)");
            return;
            }
        } while (true);
    }
    
    public static boolean invalidInput(String input) {
        if(!(input.charAt(0) == '1' || input.charAt(0) == '2' || input.charAt(0) == '3' || input.charAt(0) == '4')) {
            System.out.println("Error! Not an option!");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public static void OptionOne() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the class list or press 'B' to go back to the main menu.\n>>");
        String input = in.next();
        if (!input.equals("B")){
            File File1 = new File("C:\\Users\\myName\\eclipse-workspace\\HW4\\" + input);
            if(File1.exists()) {
                Scanner inFile = new Scanner(File1);
                while(inFile.hasNext()) {
                    String inFirstName = inFile.next();
                    String inLastName = inFile.next();
                    float inGPA= Float.parseFloat(inFile.next());
                    Student stu = new Student(inFirstName, inLastName, inGPA);
                    studentList.add(stu);
                }
                System.out.println(input + " loaded successfully!");
                logHistory.add(input);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("File does not exist!");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void OptionTwo() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type in a GPA for which you would like to display students\n>>");
        float user_input = in.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Hey");
        for(Student myStudent : studentList) {
            if(user_input <= myStudent.getGPA()) {
                System.out.println(myStudent);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void printLog() {
        for(int i=0; i<logHistory.size();i++) {
            String log = logHistory.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
            System.out.println(log);
        }
        return;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        start();
    }
}
```

Also here's an example of one of the text files I'm using:

```
Madeline    Holmes  0.3966
Cassandra   Wilkerson   1.2734
Sherman Tucker  0.8281
Ray Owen    1.6671
Irving  Klein   1.3626
Chris   Young   0.801
Ora Reynolds    0.6448
Charlie Collins 0.4683
Wayne   White   0.0056
Bobby   Price   2.9535
Troy    Keller  1.9381
Herbert Lloyd   3.1048
Anita   Robinson    2.6867
Lorene  Brady   2.8133
Wendy   Coleman 0.9067
Rochelle    Fernandez   2.5683
Wanda   Clayton 1.0686
Jamie   Simon   0.6709
Maggie  Gonzalez    3.9742
Felicia Powers  1.7226
Allison Summers 3.4843
Kristopher  Maxwell 1.4895
Donna   Rose    1.519
Sue Alvarado    0.0465
Pearl   Carlson 3.035
Abraham Rodgers 2.3123
Billie  Doyle   0.9774
Edna    Fitzgerald  3.8697
Christie    Day 0.8813
Terri   Pena    3.9045
Maria   Carpenter   2.2858
Jamie   Manning 0.9225
Rose    Bridges 1.5402
Zachary Parker  3.723
Julie   Rowe    0.9275
Javier  Warren  1.1316
Cora    Townsend    0.6736
Yvette  Rodriguez   0.2977
Gloria  Henderson   0.4383
Rafael  Weaver  1.9113
Kim Barrett 0.1046
Orlando Dunn    3.0004
Stuart  Terry   0.4609
Elaine  Davis   2.3482
Simon   Jones   3.5721
Faith   Rivera  1.1192
Jodi    Kelly   1.9566
Loren   Spencer 0.7206
Ignacio Hicks   3.3818
Johanna James   0.3527
Arturo  Huff    2.3178
Arnold  Barker  0.7946
Marc    Weber   1.1336
Joy Bush    0.6794
Brenda  Hubbard 3.0953
Carroll Romero  2.5379
Ann Moore   2.1482
Archie  Duncan  2.897
Eddie   Fields  3.1792
Jan Andrews 3.4771
Della   Waters  2.0199
Nadine  Pierce  1.3615
Carlos  Ortega  1.4948
Toni    Ross    0.1255
Israel  Carson  0.1968
Essie   Morton  3.561
Wesley  Poole   1.3881
Philip  Benson  2.071
Jonathon    Morgan  3.4305
Theresa Hunt    1.7487
Jaime   Ruiz    2.5617
Maxine  Evans   1.8658
Meghan  Hopkins 0.4686
Darnell Hines   2.8667
Rhonda  Garner  2.9759
Blake   Mills   2.0325
Cedric  Jennings    2.2025
Lisa    Miles   3.9877
Steve   Ball    1.1752
Sherri  Gutierrez   0.3944
Rudolph Cross   0.3921
Mario   Cunningham  1.5849
Eileen  Gonzales    1.2047
Tami    Malone  0.1306
Nathan  Becker  1.1747
Brett   Alexander   1.5998
Colleen Cole    2.7064
Ivan    Harris  1.539
Tiffany Gibbs   0.7235
Judith  Kim 2.8998
Christy Blake   0.7685
Gerardo Hammond 0.88
Dwight  Bailey  0.8722
Brian   Santiago    2.634
Andrew  Watkins 3.8533
Garrett Fox 1.1582
Claire  Graham  0.5412
Hubert  Mitchell    1.0085
Grant   Bowman  2.8718
Yolanda Gomez   1.2913
```

Comment: The easy way is to keep a list of loaded paths.  Have something like Collection<String> loaded = new HashSet<>() in the class keeping track of such stuff and add the file path to the list when you're done loading it.  Then simply check if loaded.contains(path) for detecting loaded data.

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Add condition that check if the input file name is already exist in your log history . You make the condition where you want.

```
public static void OptionOne() throws FileNotFoundException {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the class list or press 'B' to go back to the main menu.\n>>");
            String input = in.next();
            if (!input.equals("B")){
                if(!logHistory.contains(input)) {//check if the input file does not exist
                    File File1 = new File("C:\\Users\\myName\\eclipse-workspace\\HW4\\" + input);
                    if(File1.exists()) {
                        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(File1);
                        while(inFile.hasNext()) {
                            String inFirstName = inFile.next();
                            String inLastName = inFile.next();
                            float inGPA= Float.parseFloat(inFile.next());
                            Student stu = new Student(inFirstName, inLastName, inGPA);
                            studentList.add(stu);
                        }
                        System.out.println(input + " loaded successfully!");
                        logHistory.add(input);
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("File does not exist!");
                    }
                }
                else {//the input file exist in logHistory
                    System.out.println("File already loaded!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the `input` file was already loaded before or not. To do that you will need to check if the `input` is already in your list of loaded files. Something along the following should work:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Communicator {

    static List<String> loadedStudentLists;

    static LinkedList<Student> studentList;

    public static void start() throws Exception{
        loadedStudentLists = new ArrayList<>();
        studentList = new LinkedList<Student>();
        System.out.println("Hello professor. How can I help you?");
        displayMainMenu();
    }

    public static void displayMainMenu() throws Exception {

        String input;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.printf("1: Load student list.\n");
            System.out.printf("2: Display students by gpa.\n");
            System.out.printf("3: Print load log.\n");
            System.out.printf("4: Exit.\n");
            System.out.printf(">> ");
            input = in.next();
            if(invalidInput(input)) {
                continue;
            }

            switch(input) {
                case "1":
                    OptionOne();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    OptionTwo();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    printLog();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    System.out.println("Good bye! :)");
                    return;
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public static boolean invalidInput(String input) {
        if(!(input.charAt(0) == '1' || input.charAt(0) == '2' || input.charAt(0) == '3' || input.charAt(0) == '4')) {
            System.out.println("Error! Not an option!");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void OptionOne() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the class list or press 'B' to go back to the main menu.\n>>");
        String input = in.next();
        if (!input.equals("B")){
            if (loadedStudentLists.contains(input)) {
                System.out.println("File already loaded!");
            } else {
                File File1 = new File("C:\\Users\\myName\\eclipse-workspace\\HW4\\" + input);
                if (File1.exists()) {
                    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(File1);
                    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
                        String inFirstName = inFile.next();
                        String inLastName = inFile.next();
                        float inGPA = Float.parseFloat(inFile.next());
                        Student stu = new Student(inFirstName, inLastName, inGPA);
                        studentList.add(stu);
                    }
                    System.out.println(input + " loaded successfully!");
                    loadedStudentLists.add(input);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("File does not exist!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void OptionTwo() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type in a GPA for which you would like to display students\n>>");
        float user_input = in.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Hey");
        for(Student myStudent : studentList) {
            if(user_input <= myStudent.getGPA()) {
                System.out.println(myStudent);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printLog() {
        for(int i=0; i<loadedStudentLists.size();i++) {
            String log = loadedStudentLists.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
            System.out.println(log);
        }
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        start();
    }
}
```